# Expanders are pushing inward, how can I push them to make the window larger?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <someControl Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Expander Grid.Row="1" ExpandDirection="Right"/>
    <Expander Grid.Row="2" ExpandDirection="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

When opening the expanders on the right of the window, they end up making the control in Grid Column 0 smaller. I want the size of that control to be preserved and have the expander make more room to the right in the window when it opens. It's as if the expands are opening to the left despite I have them set to expand right. "SizeToContent" doesn't seem to have any effect on this.

EDIT: This also has the same "issue" if you do it vertically which is more traditional for expanders I suppose. Any way around it?

Comment: If the Window was full sized what would you expect it to do?

Comment: If its fullscreen, then I expect it to do that as there is no more width to obtain. But when the window is not full size, WPF typically knows how to handle that differently. For example, if I have 3 expanders by themselves with auto heights, the window resizes itself fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Width="*"` tells WPF to use all leftover space for that control, however big or small it might be. The only way that the window will expand (with `SizeToContent="Width"`) is if the control won't fit into the column any more.

You can omit `Width` for the window so that it initializes with the smallest possible width or use `MinWidth` to force your control to not shrink past a certain size.

Sample of the first approach (I removed some irrelevant parts):

```
<Window Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="Width" Height="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf "/>
            <Expander Grid.Column="1" ExpandDirection="Right">
                <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Test 1</Button>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Grid.Column="2" ExpandDirection="Right">
                <Button VerticalAlignment="Top">Test 2</Button>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: The issue I'm seeing is that if you open any of the two expanders, it will open and make TextBlock (or a control in my case) become smaller in width. Instead, I want the width of the window to expand. SizeToContent on any setting doesn't change what happens in my use.

Comment: Strange, I'm not seeing such behaviour. Have you tried the code from my example, with the TextBlock first, then trying to replace with your control?